# Pass parameters to html through code

Tags: ios, iframe, youtube-api

I have created an html and I want to load this to my webview and pass parameters namely width, height and video id.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.example.com/api"></script>

<iframe id='player' type='text/html' width='%d' height='%d' src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1" frameborder='0'>
<script type='text/javascript'>

     ..... my code/functions here

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, what I write in my code is -

```
NSString* html = nil;
NSString *htmlContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:youTubeHTMLFilePath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];


html = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlContent, 320, 208, videoId];
[self.myWebview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

But it is not able to load this html string.

Please if anyone could help me figure it out. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar use case. It works for me with `stringWithContentsOfFile:`
This is my code:

```
NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"youtube" ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlContent, 320, 208, videoId];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

If this does not work, please log the generated string.